# Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:13:6: unexpected symbol 12: 13: This R ^

Tags: kaggle

I am trying to create and run a simple `.Rmd` (RMarkdown file) on Kaggle.

When I create a new RMarkdown on Kaggle, when I click 'Run All' to run the Rmd code, I see:

```
Your Kernel is now running in the cloud.
Enter some code at the bottom of this console and press [Enter].
Session is starting...
Session started.
ERROR
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:13:6: unexpected symbol 12: 13: This R ^
```

How can I successfully run a sample RMarkdown on Kaggle?

#### Notes

- Similar problem outlined 10 days ago [here](https://www.kaggle.com/questions-and-answers/250408).

  - The comment isn't helpful (it's just a shortcut instead of pressing the 'Run All' button)
- Problem also seems to be mentioned 2 days ago [here](https://www.kaggle.com/general/251994)

#### Reproducible example

When creating a new RMarkdown on Kaggle, I do the following.

From the kaggle.com homepage, click on 'Code' on the left hand side, then on 'New Notebook':

[image]

When I do this, it is immediately clear that the interpreter doesn't lint the code correctly (look at the colours):

[image]

For reference, the language is 'RMarkdown':

[image]

And the editor type is 'Script':

[image]

And when I click 'Run All':

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Click 'Save Version' (top right of screen)

That will run (i.e. 'knit') your RMarkdown code (it may take a moment). A link to the knitted document pop up in the bottom left of screen. It's that easy!

[image]